# Перенос таблиц из MS SQL Server 2008/MS Acess 97 в H2

Tags: sql, sql-server, h2

Есть таблицы в БД на MS Acess 97 и на MS SQL Server 2008 как перенести их в БД H2?

Comment: Насколько мне известно, для Н2 имеется ODBC драйвер, а значит можно воспользоваться эспортом из MSSQL/Access

Comment: а можно поподробнее? это через PostgreSQL ODBC?

Comment: Нет. Именно драйвер для Н2. Найдите, установите, а потом используйте процедуру экспорта.